# Is it Possible to execute AsyncTask with ArrayList<ModelClass> as parameter in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, runnable

I am trying to exectue AsyncTask to download images from server in my Fragment class as :

```
GetImageTask task = new GetImageTask (getActivity());
task.execute(new String[]{ imageUrlList.get(0),  imageUrlList.get(1), imageUrlList.get(2) });
```

In doinBackground:

```
protected List<RowItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {
  rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
  Bitmap map = null;
  for (String url : urls) {
    map = downloadImage(url);
    rowItems.add(new RowItem(map));
  }
  return rowItems;
}
```

by using this Code I am able to download images from server but could not synchronize with other data information to show in Listview .

Is it possible to execute AsyncTask background with ArrayList or Is there any better approach of synchronizing downloaded images with image detail information?

Comment: You can set any object as a parameter for the AsyncTask, so ArrayList should work just fine for being passed to doInBackground

Comment: I am following this tutorial    

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/dialog/android-download-multiple-files-showing-progress-bar/ and willing to execute task with ArrayList<ModelClass> instead of "task.execute(new String[] { URL, URL1, URL2 });"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Google says in official doc you can give `RowItem` or other object types as **generic type** to `AsyncTask`.

```
public class GetImageTask extends AsyncTask<RowItem, String, List<RowItem>>
```

Your onDoingBackground method'll be like below:

```
protected List<RowItem> doInBackground(RowItem... rowItems) {
  rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
  Bitmap map = null;
  for (String url : urls) {
    map = downloadImage(url);
    rowItems.add(new RowItem(map));
  }
  return rowItems;
}
```

Here're the declarations of Type params in AsyncTask

```
X – The type of the input variables value you want to set to the background process. This can be an array of objects.

Y – The type of the objects you are going to enter in the onProgressUpdate method.

Z – The type of the result from the operations you have done in the background process.
```

You can find more information about async tasks from here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

**Note**: I suggest you to use a library for image loading operations. Because handling image downloads is much more complicated operation then it seems. (Networking, caching, memory usage etc)

There are many useful libraries for this job. You can use Otto's picasso
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Or other libraries:

Universal Image Loader:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Glide:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Fresco:
https://github.com/facebook/fresco

Good luck.

Edit2: You'll execute like:

```
myTaskInstance.execute(rowItemsList.toArray(new RowItem[]));
```

Comment: Since I am using  my SubFragment inside viewpager which lises in Parent Fragment  with in an MainActivity I found it difficult to  cache images so decided to store images and other datas to sqlite ...about your answer within doInbackground() you are looping string which is not as param in method and while executing task from asyncTask.execute how do I pass Generic type ..

Comment: i edited my answer. you can still use a library for this. also you can pass your list to AsyncTask as a constrcutor parameter but it's not safe.

Comment: Thanks @savepopulation for the answer actually I was willing to pass Arraylist with modelclass and get Output as ArrayList as Model  on postexecute .....and I did it thanks for guidelines ....